# get prefix value from below array at routes.php in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin','middleware' => 'auth'], function($router) {
    dd($router);
    include('moduleroutes.php');

});
```

I get bellow array in route.php. How i get the prefix value from this array.

```
 Router {#24 ▼
  #events: Dispatcher {#5 ▶}
  #container: Application {#2 ▶}
  #routes: RouteCollection {#26 ▶}
  #current: null
  #currentRequest: null
  #middleware: array:7 [▶]
  #middlewareGroups: array:2 [▶]
  #binders: array:1 [▶]
  #patterns: []
  #groupStack: array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▶]
    1 => array:4 [▼
      "middleware" => array:2 [▶]
      "prefix" => "/admin"        //want value "admin"
      "namespace" => "App\Http\Controllers"
      "where" => []
    ]
  ]
}
```

please guide me. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a controller you can use this to get a prefix:

```
echo $this->getRouter()->getCurrentRoute()->getPrefix();
```

**Update**

If you want to get prefix in group, you could do something like this:

```
$adminPrefix = 'admin'; // Alternatively you could keep this variable in config file.
Route::group(['prefix' => $adminPrefix, 'middleware' => 'auth'], function($router) use ($adminPrefix) {
    echo $adminPrefix;
});
```

Comment: i want it in routes.php

Comment: I don't know why do you want to do this, it looks weird, but you can use solution from **update** section of my answer.